# What is the significance of the half derivative of $x^n$?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, gamma-function

I have been researching about half derivatives, and the simplest version of a half derivative I found was $x^n$. However, this half derivative only works when n is a natural number. I feel like it is just complicating the normal derivative. Can someone tell me the significance of the half-derivative of $x^n$?

Comment: "However, this half derivative only works when n is a natural number." Have you tried $x^n = e^{n\log{(x)}}$? I know that a lot of derivations fail with $x^r$ for some real number $r$. You should try that.